# Scraping web page with Requests Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would to scrape this page but I cant find `table` with `BeautifulSoup` after requests

Code

```
headers = {"Referer": "https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive",
            'User-Agent': 'my-user-agent'
        }
url = 'https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive?year=2016'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_="results-archive-table mega-table")
print(table)
```

Output `<Response [403]>` `None`

Comment: replace white space within class name with Period `.`, to be `results-archive-table.mega-table`

Comment: That is **not** in the initial HTML - look at what `page.text` actually is.

Comment: check `page.status_code` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting `Response [200]` using `scrapy-selenium` with `selenium stealth`.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium import webdriver
from shutil import which 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class AtpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'atptour'
    chrome_path = which("chromedriver") 
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=chrome_options)
    stealth(driver,user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36',
    languages=["en-US", "en"], 
    vendor="Google Inc.", 
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.", 
    renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
    fix_hairline=False) 
  
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive?year=2016',
            wait_time =5,
            callback = self.parse,
        
        )
    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

OUTPUT:

```
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive> (referer: None)
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:53662/session/039ca0bb0a64b7b9eb48ab26a0f464a0 {}
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:53662 "DELETE /session/039ca0bb0a64b7b9eb48ab26a0f464a0 HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2021-07-31 10:25:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2021-07-31 10:25:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/response_bytes': 15142,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
```

Answer (score 2):

The websites is protected by Cloudflare and expect to be javascript enabled while accessing website just like real browsers which `requests` library can't perform. Thus, you can try with `Selenium`.

Another thing I have noticed that using `Selenium` in `headless` mode throws captcha but `non-headless` works. Finally, you can parse using `Beautifusoup`.

**Try this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_path = ('Add your chromedriver path here')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)

url = 'https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/results-archive?year=2016'
driver.get(url)
data = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_="results-archive-table mega-table")
print(table)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the response :

```
print(page)
<Response [403]>
```

Maybe you have to add some headers to your request.

Comment: I added some headers but still the issue

Comment: For heavy "Java rendered" Website , consider 'selenium' as a possibility.

Comment: to bypass Cloudfare protection you need Selenium , just to "humanize" your Bot.

Comment: @luka have a look here : https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/